# Using "neither I" as a stand alone phrase/sentence

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Is it correct to use neither I like this?

> There's nothing you could've done. Neither I.

(I couldn't search examples on Google because *neither I* is often used at the beginning of a sentence.)

Comment: You can set the search to ignore case. But it's ungrammatical.  "Nor I" would be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not correct.  A "correct" sentence would be "Nor I." But while this sentence is grammatically correct, it is quite formal, so "Nor I" will not sound correct in all circumstances.

For instance, this dialogue does not sound natural:
"Man, we really screwed up bad.  The whole system was out of wack."
"Don't worry, there's nothing you could've done.  Nor I."

To correct the sentence for that context, we might rephrase:
 "There's nothing you could have done. I couldn't have done anything either."
Or we might use the informal phrase, "Me neither."